# how to return web page within spring webservice context?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, tomcat

Suppose we use tomcat as container and we have implemented a web service server using spring web-service framework.

Now we want to provide a web page for users to access some other functions of our product in a browser instead of the client software.

The logic processing web page requests is similar to that processing web service ones. So we want to write web-page-generating codes with in the same application context as the web service.

This might be a weird need, but it is a need.

I tried to write a servlet and refer to a Service loaded by Spring, but it feels dirty and sometimes does not work:

```
class ExampleServlet{
    private FooService service = FooService.ins;

    public doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
           service.doSomething();
           // ...
           return someResponse;
    }

}

@Service
class FooService{
    public static FooService ins = null;
    public FooService(){
        ins = this;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void doSomething(){
        // ... 
    }
}
```

in web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <display-name>ExampleServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ExampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.somepackage.ExampleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ExampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/do_something</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should wrap them up in spring mvc

ref:

1. http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e950
2. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-servlet